# Cannot recover key / Failed to read key xxxxx from store "C:\projects\......\keystore": Cannot recover key

Tags: android-studio, google-play, publish

I know this has been asked before, but I haven't found any working answers yet.

It's really driving me nuts.

I have 3 apps in Google play, all published in 2016/2017 with Eclipse.

What I saved was a binary file (the keyfile I guess) for every project and some 'passwords', one for every project and one for what I saved by the name 'DistributionKeyStoreAlias' (which I used for all three?)

I can't remember how it was in Eclipse, but now in Android studio it seems like the information I have to provide has changed?

I see a 'key store path' (I pointed it to the binary file), the 'key store password' (I entered the password which I saved for the specific project) and the 'key alias' (I guessed it was the 'DistributionKeyStoreAlias' thing) and the 'key password' (I enetered the password I stored for the 'DistributionKeyStoreAlias').

But it fails with the same message, for all 3 apps!

I've tried all combinations, and it's driving me nuts. As it seems now, I can't re-publish any one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the commandline "keytool" to have a look at your keystores.
For example, try:

`keytool -v -list -keystore yourbinaryfile.keystore`

The error message should tell you what is wrong. If your binary file is not a keystore it should tell you. Otherwise, it should list the aliases of all the keys in your keystore and you can see if what you have written down the alias is, is still correct.

Comment: Can you also tell me.... I've read a lot about the 'certificate'. Is that the same as the 'key store'?

Comment: Hopefully you understand that for signing, there is a public key and a private key. You sign with the private key, and other people verify with the public key. The keystore contains both the public and private key. A certificate is the public key, in addition to some other metadata (like issuer, what it is used for, etc). So conceptually you can think of the keystore as containing one or more certificates (each with an alias) as well as the associated private key.

Comment: Thanks very much for this explanation.

Comment: Can I somehow check on the original APK with which keystore and certificate the apk was signed?

Comment: It worked!! got the name of the key from the statement you gave me (and when it asked for a password and it showed me data I knew I had at least that part correct) and after 5 tries (don't know why I had to try 5 times...) it worked!! Thanks so much